# change only specific Cell to be Upward Excel

Tags: c#, excel

My code changes the whole row, but I want to change only specific Cells like in this picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA4AT.jpg)

```
     xlWorkSheet.Rows["4"].Cells.Orientation = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpward;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change it to

```
 xlWorkSheet.Range["E4"].Cells.Orientation = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpward;
```

Comment: So this was just a typo?

Comment: I thought it selects the 4 position in the row